# What order is the search for "is:answer" showing me?

Tags: support, search, sorting

How does the "is:answer" search order the answers when sorted by relevance?

On here, Meta.SE, they are clearly sorted by votes:

> [image: Meta SE search]

On Ask Ubuntu they are neither sorted by votes or date or views, and if I click relevance again, the order changes. There is a variance in votes between 0 and 18, but none less than 0:

> [image: Ask Ubuntu search]

Skeptics may be ordered by date? Although I can't actually check for some reason - the tool tip isn't working. And anyway, they're all Feb 25th / 26th, and today is the 22nd of March.

> [image: Skeptics search]

So how is this being ordered by default, and why does it vary site to site?

Comment: "relevance" is not relevant when you have no keywords to search for.

Comment: I know, I wondered why the sites were giving very different orders.

Comment: Probably due to different indexing behind the scenes. :)

Comment: Not exactly caching, more like the code responsible for indexing.